# Neo4j TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back

Tags: exception, transactions, neo4j, rollback

I recently upgraded Neo4j from version 2.1.7 to 2.2.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2. I have been running my data collection scripts that load into the database using the following cypher command in a .cql text file:

> ```
> USING PERIODIC COMMIT
> LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 
>   'file:X:\\parsed\\TOI\\0031\\node_full_statuses.csv'
>   AS line
> MERGE (ts:TwitterStatus {id: toInt(line.id)}) 
> ON CREATE SET ts.id_str = line.id_str, ts.timestamp =  toint(line.timestamp), 
>     ts.created_at = line.created_at, ts.favorites_count = toInt(line.favorite_count),
>     ts.lang = line.lang, ts.source = line.source, ts.retweet_count = toInt(line.retweet_count),
>     ts.text = line.text, ts.truncated = line.truncated
> ON MATCH SET ts.id_str = line.id_str, ts.timestamp = toint(line.timestamp), ts.last_updated = timestamp(), 
>     ts.created_at = line.created_at, ts.favorites_count = toInt(line.favorite_count),
>     ts.lang = line.lang, ts.source = line.source, ts.retweet_count = toInt(line.retweet_count),
>     ts.text = line.text, ts.truncated = line.truncated;
> ```

This had been working without any errors in  2.1.7. Now when I use the same command:

> ```
> PS C:\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0\bin> .\Neo4jShell.bat -file X:\parsed\NDTV\0031\load_database.cql -v
> ```

I get the following exception:

> ```
> ERROR (-v for expanded information):
>     TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
> org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Transaction was marked as successful, but unable to commit transaction so rolled back.
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:126)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_2.TransactionBoundQueryContext.commitAndRestartTx(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:304)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.spi.DelegatingQueryContext.commitAndRestartTx(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:99)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compatibility$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$super$commitAndRestartTx(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:134)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$commitAndRestartTx$1.apply$mcV$sp(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:134)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$commitAndRestartTx$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:134)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$anonfun$commitAndRestartTx$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:134)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compatibility$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:182)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.commitAndRestartTx(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:134)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.spi.DelegatingQueryContext.commitAndRestartTx(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:99)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_2$executionplan$LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver$$commitAndRestartTx(LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver.scala:50)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.LoadCsvPeriodicCommitOb$$$$19575187a71575c7a3df5a5d253113c$$$$ommitObserver$$onNext$1.apply$mcV$sp(LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver.scala:46)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.UpdateCounter.resetIfPastLimit(UpdateCounter.scala:34)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_2$executionplan$LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver$$onNext(LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver.scala:46)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(LoadCsvPeriodicCommitObserver.scala:36)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.LoadCsvIterator.next(LoadCsvIterator.scala:31)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.LoadCsvIterator.next(LoadCsvIterator.scala:24)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.next(Iterator.scala:372)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.EmptyResultPipe.internalCreateResults(EmptyResultPipe.scala:29)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:118)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.createResults(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:92)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.build(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:64)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:122)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:106)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.run(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:70)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:166)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:166)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.exceptionHandlerFor2_2$.runSafely(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:104)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:165)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(PreparedPlanExecution.scala:27)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:107)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:101)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.internal.ServerExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ServerExecutionEngine.java:61)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.cypher.Start.getResult(Start.java:86)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.cypher.Using.getResult(Using.java:53)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.cypher.Start.exec(Start.java:68)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.TransactionProvidingApp.execute(TransactionProvidingApp.java:223)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractAppServer.interpretLine(AbstractAppServer.java:117)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.GraphDatabaseShellServer.interpretLine(GraphDatabaseShellServer.java:93)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemotelyAvailableServer.interpretLine(RemotelyAvailableServer.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/1427081262.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.MultipleUnderlyingStorageExceptions: Errors when closing (flushing) index updaters: (:label[5](property[0])) PreexistingIndexEntryConflictException{propertyValue=581543886377459712, addedNodeId=58110492, existingNodeId=57966629}
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexUpdaterMap.close(IndexUpdaterMap.java:101)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexingService$3.close(IndexingService.java:527)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.commit(TransactionRepresentationCommitProcess.java:86)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.commit(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:501)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.KernelTransactionImplementation.close(KernelTransactionImplementation.java:417)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:112)
>     ... 58 more
>     Suppressed: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.store.UnderlyingStorageException: PreexistingIndexEntryConflictException{propertyValue=581543886377459712, addedNodeId=58110492, existingNodeId=57966629}
>             at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexUpdaterMap.close(IndexUpdaterMap.java:93)
>             ... 63 more
>     Caused by: PreexistingIndexEntryConflictException{propertyValue=581543886377459712, addedNodeId=58110492, existingNodeId=57966629}
>             at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.UniquePropertyIndexUpdater.close(UniquePropertyIndexUpdater.java:102)
>             at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.UpdateCountingIndexUpdater.close(UpdateCountingIndexUpdater.java:65)
>             at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.ContractCheckingIndexProxy$1.close(ContractCheckingIndexProxy.java:104)
>             at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexUpdaterMap.close(IndexUpdaterMap.java:85)
>             ... 63 more
>
>  -host      Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default: localhost)
>  -port      Port of host to connect to (default: 1337)
>  -name      RMI name, i.e. rmi://<host>:<port>/<name> (default: shell)
>  -pid       Process ID to connect to
>  -c         Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits
>  -file      File containing commands to execute, or '-' to read from stdin. After executing it the shell exits
>  -readonly  Connect in readonly mode (only for connecting with -path)
>  -path      Points to a neo4j db path so that a local server can be started there
>  -config    Points to a config file when starting a local server
>
> Example arguments for remote:
>         -port 1337
>         -host 192.168.1.234 -port 1337 -name shell
>         -host localhost -readonly
>         ...or no arguments for default values
> Example arguments for local:
>         -path /path/to/db
>         -path /path/to/db -config /path/to/neo4j.config
>         -path /path/to/db -readonly
> ```

I find this very strange because when I used the merge command before I did not get any errors from duplicates (id and id_str are unique constraints). This seems to say that it is a PreexistingIndexEntryConflictException that is causing the rollback.

If I run the command line command again I get a different exception:

> ```
> PS C:\neo4j-enterprise-2.2.0\bin> .\Neo4jShell.bat -file X:\parsed\NDTV\0031\load_database.cql -v
> ERROR (-v for expanded information):
>     QueryExecutionKernelException: Node 58109560 already exists with label TwitterStatus and property "id_str"=[581520425747759104]
> org.neo4j.kernel.impl.query.QueryExecutionKernelException: Node 58109560 already exists with label TwitterStatus and property "id_str"=[581520425747759104]
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.internal.ServerExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ServerExecutionEngine.java:65)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.cypher.Start.getResult(Start.java:86)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.cypher.Using.getResult(Using.java:53)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.cypher.Start.exec(Start.java:68)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.apps.TransactionProvidingApp.execute(TransactionProvidingApp.java:223)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.impl.AbstractAppServer.interpretLine(AbstractAppServer.java:117)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.kernel.GraphDatabaseShellServer.interpretLine(GraphDatabaseShellServer.java:93)
>     at org.neo4j.shell.impl.RemotelyAvailableServer.interpretLine(RemotelyAvailableServer.java:60)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor90.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$254(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler$$Lambda$2/1427081262.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> Caused by: org.neo4j.cypher.CypherExecutionException: Node 58109560 already exists with label TwitterStatus and property "id_str"=[581520425747759104]
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compatibility$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:184)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.setProperty(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:151)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.spi.UpdateCountingQueryContext$CountingOps.setProperty(UpdateCountingQueryContext.scala:132)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.mutation.PropertySetAction.exec(PropertySetAction.scala:59)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.mutation.MergeNodeAction$$anonfun$exec$1.apply(MergeNodeAction.scala:80)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.mutation.MergeNodeAction$$anonfun$exec$1.apply(MergeNodeAction.scala:80)
>     at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.mutation.MergeNodeAction.exec(MergeNodeAction.scala:79)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_2$pipes$ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe$$exec(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:56)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPi$$$$3fd0ddfab96df657454927b510aaae$$$$ands$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:45)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.ExecuteUpdateCommandsPi$$$$3fd0ddfab96df657454927b510aaae$$$$ands$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(ExecuteUpdateCommandsPipe.scala:45)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.EmptyResultPipe.internalCreateResults(EmptyResultPipe.scala:29)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:118)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.createResults(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:92)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory$ExecutionWorkflowBuilder.build(DefaultExecutionResultBuilderFactory.scala:64)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:122)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$getExecutionPlanFunction$1.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:106)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$1.run(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:70)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:166)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper$$anonfun$run$1.apply(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:166)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.exceptionHandlerFor2_2$.runSafely(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:104)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.CompatibilityFor2_2$ExecutionPlanWrapper.run(CompatibilityFor2_2.scala:165)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.PreparedPlanExecution.execute(PreparedPlanExecution.scala:27)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:107)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:101)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.internal.ServerExecutionEngine.executeQuery(ServerExecutionEngine.java:61)
>     ... 24 more
> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.api.exceptions.schema.UniqueConstraintViolationKernelException: Node 58109560 already exists with label 5 and property 2=581520425747759104
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.validateNoExistingNodeWithLabelAndProperty(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:119)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.nodeSetProperty(ConstraintEnforcingEntityOperations.java:97)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.LockingStatementOperations.nodeSetProperty(LockingStatementOperations.java:324)
>     at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.OperationsFacade.nodeSetProperty(OperationsFacade.java:657)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.spi.v2_2.TransactionBoundQueryContext$NodeOperations.setProperty(TransactionBoundQueryContext.scala:176)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_2.spi.DelegatingOperations.setProperty(DelegatingQueryContext.scala:126)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compatibility$ExceptionTranslatingQuery
> Context$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$super$setProperty(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:151)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$setProperty$1.apply$mcV$sp(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:151)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$setProperty$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:151)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$ExceptionTranslatingOperations$$anonfun$setProperty$1.apply(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:151)
>     at org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compatibility.ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compatibility$ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext$$translateException(ExceptionTranslatingQueryContext.scala:182)
>     ... 51 more
>
>  -host      Domain name or IP of host to connect to (default: localhost)
>  -port      Port of host to connect to (default: 1337)
>  -name      RMI name, i.e. rmi://<host>:<port>/<name> (default: shell)
>  -pid       Process ID to connect to
>  -c         Command line to execute. After executing it the shell exits
>  -file      File containing commands to execute, or '-' to read from stdin. After executing it the shell exits
>  -readonly  Connect in readonly mode (only for connecting with -path)
>  -path      Points to a neo4j db path so that a local server can be started there
>  -config    Points to a config file when starting a local server
>
> Example arguments for remote:
>         -port 1337
>         -host 192.168.1.234 -port 1337 -name shell
>         -host localhost -readonly
>         ...or no arguments for default values
> Example arguments for local:
>         -path /path/to/db
>         -path /path/to/db -config /path/to/neo4j.config
>         -path /path/to/db -readonly
> ```

This is a transaction at the start of the 1000 line commit cycle. All 1000 lines are in the database. (I have removed them individually and get the same Exception and the nodeID increases by 1) I need to remove the 1000 lines of the commit cycle that the initial bad transaction was in to get the script to move forward.

My question is: Is there a way to fix this so that the merge works correctly without getting this weird exception on a transaction that Neo4j says looks good but it won't commit?

I do not think my work around is very good and would appreciate any advise.

Comment: Would you be able to share your source file and the index/constraint creation commands you used on the db? Was the db created with 2.2 or upgraded from 2.1.7 Would it be possible to share your graph.db/messages.log ?

Comment: The commands I used for the indexes were:   ` 
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (tweet:TwitterStatus) ASSERT tweet.id IS UNIQUE;  
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (tweet:TwitterStatus) ASSERT tweet.id_str IS UNIQUE;  
CREATE INDEX ON :TwitterStatus(timestamp);`  
  
The database was created in a previous version of neo4j (pre 2.1.7) and upgraded to 2.2. The source file is 5MB and 16815 lines long and I will need to know where to send it and the messages.log file.

Comment: please send it to michael at neo4j.org